# Are projections determined by their action on a full-rank density matrix?

Tags: measurement, density-matrix, linear-algebra, projection-operator

Consider (self-adjoint) projections $P$ and $Q$ defined on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space. If $\rho$ is the maximally-mixed state, then we have that $P \rho P = Q \rho Q$ implies $P = Q$, since $\rho$ is proportional to the identity operator. Does this implication also hold if $\rho$ is instead any density operator with full rank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Clearly, ${\rm Ker}(P) \subset {\rm Ker}(P\rho P)$.

On the other hand, since $\rho$ is a density operator and has full rank, we have $\rho > 0$, that is, $\langle x | \rho | x \rangle > 0$ for any non-zero vector $|x\rangle \in H$.

In particular, for any $|x\rangle \notin {\rm Ker}(P)$ we have $\langle x | P\rho P | x \rangle > 0$ since $P | x \rangle \neq 0$. Thus, $|x\rangle \notin {\rm Ker}(P\rho P)$. This means that $H \setminus {\rm Ker}(P) \subset H \setminus {\rm Ker}(P\rho P)$.

Overall, we have ${\rm Ker}(P\rho P) = {\rm Ker}(P)$, and thus ${\rm Ker}(P) = {\rm Ker}(Q)$.